# Murder mystery on 1st day of school

Tags: strategy

On the first day of school there has already been a murder! There are four suspects and here is their stories:

> The math teacher says he was giving a test to his students.
>
> The librarian was sorting books.
>
> The principal was giving a tour of the school.
>
> And last, but not least, the janitor was cleaning up the bathroom.

**Who is the Murderer?**

Comment: You’ve gone to school or most of you have. So this answer should be clear

Comment: I think this needs to be clearer, it feels like there are too many answers. Who was the principal giving a tour to? If it was to all students, then how could the maths teacher be giving a test? Was the test to non-first yearers, and the tour was to first-yearers? The librarian and janitor both wouldnt have an alibi but the others would if their stories were true. I think this needs a bit more detail.

Comment: It feels like this is a terrible play on [another puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/which-teacher-is-the-murderer), where the maths teacher claims to be _grading_ tests. Here, the teacher would've been alone and therefore have no alibi, and there would be no tests to grade.

Comment: I like how it's phrased "there has already been a murder!" as if school murders are inevitable. And to add to a (large) list of possible solutions, the bathroom shouldn't have been used over the holidays.

Comment: Perhaps this puzzle has to do something with a **collection of crows**  :-P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which teacher is the murderer?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/which-teacher-is-the-murderer)

Comment: I think no one from them is murderer, as it says "there has already been a murder", may means murder before that first day.

Comment: It's the janitor — I mean, *nobody suspects the murderer to be the janitor*, so it is the janitor.

Answer (score 4):

The murderer is:

> The math teacher.

Why:

> Because she **SAYS** she was giving a test to the students, which can be false. The rest of the statements should be true, because is not what they say, but are exactly what they did during the murder.

Comment: Good observation. ^ voted.

Comment: I mean, why *is* the math(s) teacher giving out a test on the first day of school? Perhaps it was a revision test (or pre-test, you might call it), but now we have to include an assumption ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's:

> The librarian

Since:

> No-one has borrowed or returned any books, so the books don't need to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on data given it could be

> The maths teacher

As,

> On day one no tests are usually conducted.

Comment: What about a unit pre-test?

Comment: Well, 1st day is considered as day one of academic year. In such a case, perhaps there is no possibility of conducting any kind of test.

Comment: I have found in my experience that my teachers often start with an introductory test so they know where best to spend their time teaching.

Comment: math teacher will have the students as alibi. Why would the teacher take the risk knowing this?

Comment: Perhaps a determined murderer does not think prior to his/her actions... but definitely after!

Answer (score 1):

> janitor

My deductions are based on having an alibi

> Math teacher would have an alibi of students.
>  Principal would also have an alibi.
>  The tour of the school also involves library. The librarian would also have an alibi.

Answer (score 0):

I think

> there is not enough information to determine who it is. 
>  Why is the math teacher giving a test on the first day? It could be a **pre-test**, to determine what the students already know. 
>  How about the librarian or the janitor? Why aren't the books already sorted, and the bathrooms already clean if it is only the first day? Perhaps there was **summer school**. 
>  Why is the principal giving a tour? It's the **first day**.
> It could be any of them, or none at all.